# Bash script to calculate and compare checksums

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a small bashscript to calculate the checksum of a file, and compare it to a given one.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-f <file>] [-h <hash>] [-m <md5|sha256|...>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo "No arguments supplied!"
   usage
fi

while getopts ":h:m:f:" opt; do
   case "${opt}" in
      h )
         sum=${OPTARG}
         ;;
      m )
         method=${OPTARG}
         ;;
      f )
         file=${OPTARG}
         ;;
      : )
         usage
         ;;
      \? )
         usage
         ;;
   esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

method="${method}sum"
echo "${sum} ${file}" | ${method} -c
```

The script works as it should - of course only as long as the arguments make sense. 
But if I enter something like `./checksum.sh -fm`, so there should be a '?' in *opt* as there is a missing argument, the corresponding case is not executed and the script doesn't exit. 
As $method is empty, the error message is

```
invalid option -- 'c'
Try 'sum --help' for more information.
```

Why doesn't this work, and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The title of your post is misleading, because the problem you are discussing here relates only to the correct usage of *getopts*, and not what you do with the parameters afterwards.

You have defined your options as to require an argument. For instance, calling your script as

```
./checksum.sh -fxxxx
```

is equivalent to

```
./checksum.sh -f xxxx
```

and means that `file` is set to *xxxx*. If you invoke it as

```
./checksum.sh -fm
```

it means that `file` is set to *m*  and `method` stays empty.

Answer (score 1):

There are no mandatory options with `getopt`. If some of your options are mandatory you must check the corresponding variables before using them:

```
declare method=""
while getopts ":h:m:f:" opt; do
  ...
done
if [ -z "$method" ]; then
  usage
fi
```

In case you have a default value for an option simply initialize it before parsing your options:

```
declare method="sha256"
while getopts ":h:m:f:" opt; do
  ...
done
if [ -z "$method" ]; then
  usage
fi
```

This way it will pass the post-test even if its value has not been modified by the corresponding option.